# HTTP REST. Можно ли в body отправлять пакет из JSON

Tags: json, rest

Имею такую проблему. Один сервис (потребитель) отправляет другому (поставщику) POST через REST API. По протоколу к этому POST в body прикреплен JSON с передаваемыми параметрами. Да вот беда какая. Поставщик ждет на входе объект (object), а потребителю вот очень -очень надо передавать массив (array of object). Ну то есть выглядит это таким оразом, поставщик ждет от вас инфо о каждом товаре в отдельности, а вы можете передавать сведения о товарах только "пачкой", то есть о всех товарах сразу.
Полазив по интернету, я увидел что в body можно прикреплять батч из JSON , перечилив их массивом и снабдив каждый из них своим "id". Но к сожалению не нашел нигде какноническую документацию на формирование таких пакетов. Подскажите, возможно ли это и правильно ли я рассуждаю на счет отправки сведений пакетом в рамках одного запроса POST?

Comment: Нет никакой канонической документации REST, фактически каждый делает как хочет. Если поставщик умеет принимать только по одному объекту, то массив ему никак не передать. Нужно смотреть подробно описание API поставщика. Если там не описан способ передачи массива, значит никак не получится.

Comment: как тогда быть с механизмом, описанным тут https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/graph/json-batching?

Comment: Данный механизм касается только [Microsoft Graph](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/graph/) (ваша ссылка ведет на раздел его документации).

Comment: Очень жаль(((((